# Using HTML skills in development

Tags: visualforce, lightning, html, lightning-web-components, web

I have knowledge of HTML / CSS and some basics of JavaScript, where and how can I use this knowledge in developing on the Salesforce platform?

I know VisualForce and Lightnin Web Components use HTML. Am I right? What can you advise me, dear forum users

***FYI:*** I do not know Java or Apex, for me it is difficult to learn programming languages.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, if you're unwilling or unable to learn Apex code, you will likely not have much of a future in developing Visualforce (VF) or Lightning Aura Components (LC). These technologies heavily rely on Apex. It is true that you can do quite a bit in just JavaScript (JS) with these technologies, but you need more than "some basics of JavaScript." You need mastery of JS to avoid most of the use of Apex. Likewise, Lightning Web Components (LWC) requires mastery of even more modern JavaScript, though the trade-off is you'll need less Apex for many common tasks.

If you're serious about becoming a Salesforce Developer, I strongly recommend that you take a course or read a book in Programming Logic, then learn Apex and JavaScript. Without these skills, you're going to be severely impaired in your capabilities. In addition, VF, LC, and LWC all introduce custom components aside from just HTML. Your HTML skills will still be useful, but you'll need to learn about entirely new elements and how they work, and how to combine those with HTML.

Aside from Programming Logic, you'll also need to learn how to read Documentation. Even "senior-level" developers like myself use the documentation at least a few times a week. If you can't do research, programming probably isn't for you. Without knowledge of Apex, you'll be limited to built-in methods for retrieving and modifying data, which are fine for trivial tasks like updating a record or creating forms that might be used with external systems, but it'll be just really basic entry-level stuff that most Salesforce Administrators could probably do.

---

That said, your skills are perfectly adequate if you just want to be a System Administrator. Having a bit of knowledge in programming can help admins diagnose problems in developer code, which is a very handy skill to have. You may want to pursue a career in Salesforce Administration if you find programming to be too daunting.

*NOTE*: This answer is not meant to discourage readers. I am simply trying to convey that programming is not something someone can pick up in a few hours. It requires dedication to the art, and a commitment to countless hours of practice, research, designing algorithms, and so on. Simply learning HTML and CSS makes for a great web designer (and that's a definitely lucrative career choice), but learning programming logic is what makes a great developer.